# Angular 2/4 authentication with SAML

Tags: angular, authentication, saml-2.0, keycloak

I'm working on a project which has strict standards for security measures and must be implemented with a SSO SAML standard for authentication and of course use XML based security token services.

We're using Keycloak as our IdP, which so far I've implemented my Angular2 based app on the frontend only with OpenID as a POC but as I said above this will not be a requirement. On the backend we're using Vert.x and Spring boot and they have not problem with this integration.

After extensive research on the subject I found out that auth0 using their platform can provide this as a service. This is a problem because we've already chosen Keycloak as our main identity and access management solution, and from what I gathered as info so far it won't be changed because "we're in too deep".

My question given this situation, are there any solutions for the frontend integration with the Keycloak and SAML? Given that it's a must to use those standards.

Scouring the internet I found very little information about this specific type of implementation and do not posses the extensive knowledge to see how this can be done.

Any aid on how it can be executed is welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: Also looking for solution to authentication with SAML for Angular. However, everything seems to be pointing towards JWT\

Comment: @Colum We discussed it with our team and a change had to be made, and the most sensible solution was to use a hybrid system. On the top, the IDP and the browser would communicate through a SSL/TLS connection with openID/JWT and in the back the machine to machine communication would also be using TLS and the SAML protocol where it's needed. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your comment! We also had a lot of issue with this. I will pass your suggestion on to the team handling the auth section. For now, we also have had to change how the system works and the plans are being discussed on whether to move away from it completely or to use a hybrid solution or to build an ECP implementation.